# How to disable disallowadhocaccess in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get data from another database using the `OPENDATASOURCE` command, but I get an error about DisallowAdHocAccess.

The SQL Server version is 2008 Express Edition, running on a remote site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OPENROWSET can be used to access remote data from OLE DB data sources
>   only if the DisallowAdhocAccess registry option is explicitly set to
>   0. When this option is not set, the default behavior does not allow ad
>   hoc access.

[HOW TO: Use the DisallowAdHocAccess Setting to Control Access to Linked Servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327489)

[Accessing External Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188313.aspx)

> An ad hoc name is used for infrequent queries against OLE DB data
>   sources that are not defined as linked servers. In SQL Server, the
>   OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE functions provide connection information
>   for accessing data from OLE DB data sources.   By default, ad hoc
>   names are not supported. The DisallowAdhocAccess provider option must
>   be set to 0 and the Ad Hoc Distributed Queries advanced configuration
>   option must be enabled.
>
> Security Note
>
> Enabling the use of ad hoc names means that any authenticated login to
>   SQL Server can access the provider. SQL Server administrators should
>   enable this feature only for highly trusted providers that are safe to
>   be accessed by any local login.
>
> OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE should be used only to reference OLE DB
>   data sources that are accessed infrequently. For any data sources that
>   will be accessed more than several times, define a linked server.
>   Neither OPENDATASOURCE nor OPENROWSET provide all the functionality of
>   linked server definitions. This includes security management and the
>   ability to query catalog information. Every time that these functions
>   are called, all connection information, including passwords, must be
>   provided.

Comment: Some questions.. In which server should the DisallowAdhocAccess be set? The one executing the queries or the receiving end?

Comment: On the end defining the linked server.